# Print first letter of every word, then 2nd letter, then 3rd, etc

Tags: javascript

Sorry I'm fairly new at javascript

My current output, from user inputing 'what a beautiful day':

```
what
abea
utif
ulda
y
```

how can I take the first letter of each word to get an output of something like this:

```
wauuy hbtl aeid tafa
```

I tried this:

```
var output = '';
var counter = 0;
var newStr2 = newStr.split('\n');

  for (let i = 0; i < newStr2.length; i++) {
    output = output + newStr2[counter].substr(0,1)
    counter++
  }
```

Is there a way maybe to read rows and columns? that way I can take first letter of every row then column

Thanks.

Comment: What determines the number of words in the output? The number of words in the input?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes. Its basically taking the first letter of every row in each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve using two for loops. One for each letter in the word and one for each element of the array(no of words).

```js
var newStr = `what
abea
utif
ulda
y`

var output = '';
var newStr2 = newStr.split('\n');

  for(var j = 0; j < newStr2[0].length; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < newStr2.length; i++) {
      if(newStr2[i][j]) {
        output = output + newStr2[i][j];
      }      
    }
    output += ' ';
  }
  
  console.log(output);
```

UPDATE:
The if condition is to check whether some word has that no of characters. For example, last word contains only one character(y). Therefor in new output it prints `undefined` for other places. So we check whether the word contains a character in that index and if not just ignores. Check the following code and you will understand better.

```js
var newStr = `what
abea
utif
ulda
y`

var output = '';
var newStr2 = newStr.split('\n');

  for(var j = 0; j < newStr2[0].length; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < newStr2.length; i++) {
      output = output + newStr2[i][j];
    }
    output += ' ';
  }
  
  console.log(output);
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: though could you explain `if(newStr2[i][j]) {
        output = output + newStr2[i][j];
      }` not too sure what's happening there.

Comment: @itstman I updated the answer with the explanation since it is too long to explain here in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to split every 4th character of the input (sans spaces) into an array, then use `reduce` to combine them together:

```js
function transform(input) {
  const wordCount = input.split(' ').length;
  const chunked = input.replace(/ /g, '')
  .match(new RegExp('\\w{1,' + wordCount + '}', 'g'));
  const output = chunked.reduce((accum, chunkWord) => {
    [...chunkWord].forEach((char, i) => (
      accum[i] = (accum[i] || '') + char
    ));
    return accum;
  }, {});
  return output;
}

console.log(transform('what a beautiful day'));
console.log(transform('foo foo bar bar'));
console.log(transform('fooo bar baz'));
```